# Change javascript logo depending on a IF, ELSE statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i am making 2 sites and depending on a array i have already programmed the logo should change. I am trying to use JavaScript for this.

The venue variable has been programmed and works correctly so i just need to fill in the parts under the if statements. The logos both have the same class as they will be inserted exactly in the same spot but obviously change depending on which if statement is true.

How do i get this if statement to work with images? any advice would be great.

Here my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                //this not working yet changes the logo depending on the selected location
            if (venue = "london"){
            //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE ?
            }
            else if (venue = "Manchester")
            {
                //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE?

            </script>
                    //THIS IS MY IMAGES
                    <img class="logo1" src="image1"/>
                      <img class="logo1" src="image2"/>
```

Comment: where do you want to load image?

Comment: Because the logo needs to change depending on the venue array which is already developed.. so if venue is london i need to show a different logo to if venues in manchester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do something like this, with the help of **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method in jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$('img.logo1').attr('src',venue=='london'?'image1':(venue=='Manchester'?'image2':''));
```

---

Also you can try the following method as suggested by [**Ismael Miguel**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2729937/ismael-miguel) in the comment

```
var imgs={london:'image1',manchester:'image2'};
$('img.logo1').attr('src',imgs[(venue+'').toLowerCase()]);
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="logo1" src=""/>
```

Comment: Why not `var imgs={london:'image1',manchester:'image2'}; [...].attr('src',imgs[(venue+'').toLowerCase()]);`?

Comment: You can add it to your answer, separated by a `<hr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`

Comment: Doesn't really help w/ the images, but a good point nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing for equality with a single =. Try changing

```
if (venue = "london"){
 //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE ?
}
else if (venue = "Manchester")
{
 //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE?
```

to

```
if (venue === "london"){
 //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE ?
}
else if (venue === "Manchester")
{
 //SOMETHING TO OUTPUT PICTURE?
```

Check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by many possible way. What I recommande you is to add class to your images like so:

**HTML**

```
<img class="logo1 hidden london" src="image1"/>
<img class="logo1 hidden manchester" src="image2"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden{display:none}
```

**JS*

```
if (venue == "london"){
   $('.london').removeClass('hidden'); 
}
else if (venue == "Manchester")
{
   $('.manchester').removeClass('hidden); 
}
```

Comment: Missing closing quote on hidden. Also, there are solutions that don't involve loading both images every time, if it matters for the application.